# R multiple lines in one graph with timestamp

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I would like to have three values on one graph. So far I can have 3 lines if I convert Timestamp to date

```
MyData$Timestamp <- as.Date(MyData$Timestamp)
```

but I would like to have also hour on my graph. Following my sample data

```
            Timestamp Systolic.pressure Diastolic.pressure Pulse
1 2017-06-01 23:35:31               125                 80    70
2 2017-06-02 23:35:43               130                 90    89
3 2017-06-02 23:35:43               135                 93    96
4 2017-06-03 23:35:56               140                 90    98
```

is there any way to convert Timestamp do date and time?

Comment: `?as.POSIXct` may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` to convert the time stamps to date/time. You also need to convert the data frame from wide-long format, with one column for variable names and another for their values. `tidyr::gather` can do that.

I would not place all variables on one plot because the blood pressure measurements have different units to the pulse measurements. Dual y-axes is a possible, but not recommended, solution for that.

I also wonder whether, as in your example, there can be different values at the same time? I would think this unlikely given the nature of the data.

So here's one possible solution, using facets. I've dropped row 3 from your example data for this plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

MyData %>% 
  mutate(ts = ymd_hms(Timestamp)) %>% 
  # next line just drops row 3
  slice(c(1:2, 4)) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -Timestamp, -ts) %>% 
  # reorder the variables for facets
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("Systolic.pressure", "Diastolic.pressure", "Pulse"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ts, val)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_grid(var ~ ., scales = "free") + 
    labs(x = "timestamp", y = "value") +
    theme_light()
```

[image]